# Compose XML using OLE Automation Objects in Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, ole

I try to compose XML-document using OLE Automation Objects in MS SQL SERVER.

```
DECLARE @xml_out INT
DECLARE @xml_string VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @root_elem INT
DECLARE @parent_child_node        INT
DECLARE @child_elem INT 
DECLARE @append_child INT   

EXECUTE sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0',@xml_out OUTPUT

EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @xml_out,'createElement',@root_elem OUTPUT,'root'
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @xml_out,'documentElement.appendChild',@parent_child_node OUTPUT,@root_elem 

EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @parent_child_node

EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @xml_out,'createElement',@child_elem OUTPUT,'child'
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @root_elem,'appendChild',@append_child OUTPUT,@child_elem

set @xml_string = ''
EXECUTE sp_OAGetProperty @xml_out,'xml',@xml_string OUTPUT
print 'result XML:'
print @xml_string
EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @xml_out
```

But I've got an error when I try to append child to my document:

[image: error:]

So my document will not be composed.
The expected result is next:

```
<root>
  <child/>
</root>
```

Could anybody say me what's wrong?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? The most recent versions have real support for XML.

Comment: SQL Server 2014. But I need to use OLE objects for this purpose necessarily

Comment: Why do you need to use the OLE objects?

Comment: All project uses OLE objects for XML. My listing is only example. In real  project this XML-document is composed in different procedures. And if I want to use simple XML objects instead of OLE, I will have to do refactoring of all project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `appendChild()` method on the XML document directly without having to access `documentElement` property first :

```
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @xml_out,'appendChild',@parent_child_node OUTPUT,@root_elem
```